# how to get name of json object and print it on log in android

Tags: android

```
"2019-09-06 05:55:00": {
            "1. open": "1221.6000",
            "2. high": "1221.8000",
            "3. low": "1219.7000",
            "4. close": "1220.2000",
            "5. volume": "149317"
        },
 "2019-09-06 05:50:00": {
            "1. open": "1222.3500",
            "2. high": "1223.4500",
            "3. low": "1221.1500",
            "4. close": "1221.5500",
            "5. volume": "154134"
        },
```

how to print on log of this json object name , (2019-09-06 05:55:00) in android.

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject1.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject json_data1 = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("2019-09-06 05:55:00");
    Log.e(TAG, "parseResponse: json_data1"+json_data1 );
    JsonObject objs2 = (JsonObject) jsonObject1.get("2019-09-06 05:55:00");
    Log.e(TAG, "parseResponse: ............."+objs2);
}
```

Comment: it's not a standard JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Pass your json object in this method
public void parseJSONKeyValue(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    try {
        // Iterate your json object keys
        Iterator iterator = jsonObject.keys();

        // Initiate the for loop
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            // Parsing json keys
            String jsonKey = (String) iterator.next();

            // Parsing json values
            String jsonValue = jsonObject.getString(jsonKey);

            // Printing the log
            Log.d("Json Data", "key: " + jsonKey + ", value: " + jsonValue);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("OOPs!!", "Please check your json or something else bad happened!!");
    }
}
```

Also, this JSON is not in the correct format, so you have to create a JSONArray for this.